# Correlation function with addition and subtraction in the arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, correlation

I have two columns of market data.  I'm using the correlation function correcting, starting with cells `A1:A100, B1:B100`.  I want to determine several other correlations.  One of the correlations I want to calculate is the `A2:A100, B1:B99`.  But I would like to express the cells in a function.  So let's say in cell `C1` I type 1.  I want to express the arrays as `A(1+$C$1):A100, B1:B(100-$C$1)`.  Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Look up the indirect function.  It would look something like

```
=indirect("A" & 1+$C$1 & ":A100,b1:b" & 100-$C$1)
```

which returns  `A2:A100,B1:B99` that can be passed to another function

Although I think for most functions you would need to use multiple indirect functions instead of a single like this.  I'm not sure what you can do with an indirect function that returns two arrays separated by a comma.

Something like this would be used

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("A" & 1+$C$1 & ":A100"),INDIRECT("B1:B"& 100-$C$1))
```

Comment: Fantastic!!!!!!!!!!  Instead of SUMPRODUCT, I used CORREL and got the right answer.  Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Best in general to avoid volatile INDIRECT constructions if possible:

`=CORREL(INDEX(A:A,1+$C$1):A100,B1:INDEX(B:B,100-$C$1))`

Regards